# ¿Cómo mostrar el siguiente número primo de un número dado por el usuario?

Tags: python, números-primos

```
def esPrimo(n):
    cont = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n%i==0:
            cont = cont + 1
    if cont==2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
entrada = int(input("Ingrese un numero natural: "))
if esPrimo(entrada):
    print("Es primo")
else:
    print("No es primo")
```

Estoy calculando números primos, pero necesito que el usuario me ingrese un número y el programa me muestre el primo siguiente.

Comment: No se entiende bien cuál es el problema en si

Comment: el usuario tiene que ingresar un numero n y el programa me tiene que mostrar el siguiente numero primo mas cercano a ese numero n

Comment: Esta explicando lo que quiere que haga el script, supongo que algo no esta funcionando, pero no lo explica ni lo expone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya tienes casi todo, solamente te faltaría que siga probando números mientras `esPrimo` sea `False` y pare cuando vuelva a devolver `True`:

```
def esPrimo(n):
    cont = 0
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            cont = cont + 1
    if cont == 2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
        
entrada = int(input("Ingrese un numero natural: ")) + 1

while not esPrimo(entrada):
    entrada += 1
print(entrada)
```

Ten en cuenta que en `int(input("Ingrese un numero natural: ")) + 1` hay que sumar uno para que empiece a buscar a partir del siguiente número, ya que si el que se ha introducido es primo y no lo has puesto, devolvería ese mismo número.

Ejemplos de entradas `E` y salidas `S` que te dará:

```
  E     S
-15  >  2
  2  >  3
 25  >  29
 29  >  31
 89  >  97
```

Comment: muchisimas greacias :D me sirvio

Comment: gracias idolo, ya puse el tick como hago para votar positivamente? y hay alguna forma de seguirte? o de seguir a otros usuarios?

Comment: Creo que necesitas algo más de reputación para eso, pero simplemente lo digo para que lo tengas en cuenta, que se agradece. En cuanto a seguir a usuarios, creo que no se puede, o al menos no lo he visto.

Answer (score 0):

lo único que tienes al momento de poner las condicionales es verificar que dato bool te devuelve

```
 def esPrimo(n):
    cont = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        if n%i==0:
            cont = cont + 1
    if cont==2:
        return True
    else:
        return False
entrada = int(input("Ingrese un numero natural: "))
if (esPrimo(entrada) == true):
    print("El numero es primo")
    print ("El siguiente numero es",entrada + 1)

else:
    print("No es primo")
```

de esta forma comprobamos que es un primo y a la entrada le sumamos 1

Comment: muchas, muchas gracias me sirvio de ayuda :D

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte, recuerda verificar alguna solución para que otros usuarios sepan que hay una solución útil, saludos